# How can I check input validation for negative values in a 2D array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

just a quick question here. I am trying to check for negative values for input validation, I want my program to only accept positive value only for the user input, this is my code here.

```
  //loop to array.
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //loop to row first
  {
    //take in input into data. 
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) //loop to column
    {
      //take input data.
      cout <<"Monkey " << i+1 <<" ";
      cout <<"Day " << j +1  << ":";
      cin >> pound_food[i][j]; 

      if(pound_food[i][j] < 0)
      {
        cout <<"Invalid number, number can't be negative, please try again\n";
        break;
      }

    }
```

I try to break out the loop or continue when they find the negative number, however it just keep end up storing the number even though I don't want negative number to store in the array. I just want it to store positive integer only and re prompt the user to enter the number again. I can't figure out why, I hope to hear you guys opinion!

Comment: You are storing the number in the array and then checking the sign.

Comment: `cin >> pound_food[i][j];` -- Isn't it a little too late, since you've already messed up the 2D array with the value you don't want to store?  How about storing the input in a temporary variable, checking it, and if it's ok, *then* store it in the 2D array?

Comment: Ah I will give it a try, thank you for the advice!

Comment: I was about the code the for the temporary variable then I saw Paul's comment :) Anyway, @Verax11 if you like the people's answer(s) , you could give them up vote, selecting one of them as the real answer etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter a negative number, then instead of `break`ing out of the entire column loop, you can just decrement the column index `j`. This way, the next number will be inserted into the same position where the negative number was just inserted:

```
if(pound_food[i][j] < 0)
{
    cout <<"Invalid number, number can't be negative, please try again\n";
    --j;  // instead of break
}
```

Comment: I see, I didnt know you can do something like that. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is write an inner `while` loop, and only break out until the input is ok:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) //loop to column
{
  //take input data.
  cout <<"Monkey " << i+1 <<" ";
  cout <<"Day " << j +1  << ":";
  bool ok = false;
  while (!ok)
  {   
     cin >> pound_food[i][j]; 
     if(pound_food[i][j] < 0)
        cout <<"Invalid number, number can't be negative, please try again\n";
     else
        ok = true;
  }
}
```

Or:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) //loop to column
{
  //take input data.
  cout <<"Monkey " << i+1 <<" ";
  cout <<"Day " << j +1  << ":";
  while (true)
  {   
     cin >> pound_food[i][j]; 
     if(pound_food[i][j] < 0)
        cout <<"Invalid number, number can't be negative, please try again\n";
     else
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I did not know you can do something like this haha. Thank you !